# Random values in dictionary- python

Tags: python, random

I have this `OrderedDict`:

```
(
  [
    ('Joe', ['90', '0']),
    ('Alice', ['100', '0']),
    ('Eva', ['90', '5']),
    ('Clare', ['100', '10']),
    ('Bob', ['100', '5'])
  ]
)
```

I have to create a function that takes the `OrderedDict` as an argument, generates a random performance value using normal distribution and returns these in an `OrderedDict` with names as keys.

The result should look like this:

```
([("Joe",91.362718),("Bob",100.0)...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you would like to have something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from scipy.stats import norm

ordered_dict = OrderedDict(
  [
    ('Joe', ['90', '0']),
    ('Alice', ['100', '0']),
    ('Eva', ['90', '5']),
    ('Clare', ['100', '10']),
    ('Bob', ['100', '5'])
  ]
)


def draw_normal(input_dict):
    result = []
    for key in input_dict:
        loc, scale = input_dict[key]
        random_number = norm.rvs(loc=float(loc), scale=float(scale))
        result.append((key, random_number))
    return OrderedDict(result)

print draw_normal(ordered_dict)
```

The output:

```
OrderedDict([('Joe', 90.0), ('Alice', 100.0), ('Eva', 93.55249306218722), ('Clare', 105.280646961399), ('Bob', 104.29299844957707)])
```